# Image tagging on website (like Facebook) where tags are stored in database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-applications

Does anyone know of a image tagging solution for websites that reads and writes the tag data to a database instead of a locally stored file? I've looked at http://jquery-notes.rydygel.de/index.php but the current version doesn't have database support. I just need a solution that can be used on all the mainstream browsers. The reason I don't want to read and write from a local file is because there might be a lot of images, and I don't want to store everything locally. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a "mainstream browsers" support issue - surely you'll be storing to a database server side?

Comment: Yeah. I just need the webpage to grab data from the DB (or since I'm using Django, I could pass in the results there)? I'm just not sure if there's a solution out there that does that already though. What I meant by mainstream browser support is something on the client-side like javascript, HTML 5 or basically anything that most modern browsers would support in order to do the tagging with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be need to store the notes to a database table with following rows

```
ID
IMAGE_ID
LEFT
TOP
WIDTH
HEIGHT
DATE
NOTE
AUTHOR
LINK
```

And i believe the plugin has a php class for retrieving the notes. The file is notes.class.php

Comment: Looking at the source code for notes.class.php, it seems like as of now it only supports reading notes from local files. That would mean I would need to edit the PHP code so that it would retrieve the results from the database, is that correct? I've never really dealt with PHP before so I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that :P

Comment: Yes, you will to store it the notes in the database so you they can be viewable in the long run.If you just store it in the localstorage, theyll just be cleared when the user clears it cookies.

Comment: Alright, time to learn some PHP... luckily there are plenty of examples online :D

Comment: Go to youtube and find jreamdesign,newboston and phpacademy. Look for bucky

Comment: Do you know what to do if I'm trying to run the plugin, and it keeps displaying "loading notes"?